# How can I break an email address into different parts in php?

Tags: php, javascript

Basically what I want to do is display an email using javascript to bring the parts together and form a complete email address that cannot be visible by email harvesters.

I would like to take an email address eg info@thiscompany.com and break it to:
$variable1 = "info";
$variable2 = "thiscompany.com";

All this done in PHP.

Regards,
JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one before you roll your own (it does a lot more):

```
function hide_email($email)

{ $character_set = '+-.0123456789@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  $key = str_shuffle($character_set); $cipher_text = ''; $id = 'e'.rand(1,999999999);

  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($email);$i+=1) $cipher_text.= $key[strpos($character_set,$email[$i])];

  $script = 'var a="'.$key.'";var b=a.split("").sort().join("");var c="'.$cipher_text.'";var d="";';

  $script.= 'for(var e=0;e<c.length;e++)d+=b.charAt(a.indexOf(c.charAt(e)));';

  $script.= 'document.getElementById("'.$id.'").innerHTML="<a href=\\"mailto:"+d+"\\">"+d+"</a>"';

  $script = "eval(\"".str_replace(array("\\",'"'),array("\\\\",'\"'), $script)."\")"; 

  $script = '<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/'.$script.'/*]]>*/</script>';

  return '<span id="'.$id.'">[javascript protected email address]</span>'.$script;

}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your insight, this is what I wanted to do:

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- // hide from old browsers

//variables
var part_1 = "info"; 
var part_2 = "mycompany.com"; 
 
//output
document.write('<a href=\"mailto:' + part_1 + '@' + part_2 + '\">'); 
document.write(part_1 + '@' + part_2);
document.write('</a>');
 
// -->
</script> 

I'm grateful to zaf, your solution does it perfectly.

Thanks again,
JB

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 6):

```
list($variable1, $variable2) = explode('@','info@thiscompany.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$parts = explode("@", $email_address);
```

Assuming that `$email_address = 'info@thiscompany.com'` then `$parts[0] == 'info'` and `$parts[1] == 'thiscompany.com'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explode](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.explode.php&ei=C0LHS63EIJWekQXtt8SdCQ&usg=AFQjCNH-CAfY93hbMbjmRZX-0dg8Lot4nQ&sig2=WHSPXWBFsNl4w_bZKzlfhw):

```
$email = 'info@thiscompany.com';

$arr = explode('@',$email);

$part1 = $arr[0]; // info
$part2 = $arr[1]; // thiscompany.com
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$email = "info@thiscompany.com";
$parts = explode("@", $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a function for parsing strings according to a given format: [sscanf](http://php.net/sscanf). For example:

```
sscanf('info@thiscompany.com', '%[^@]@%s', $variable1, $variable2);
```